# Why are there users whose username is shown in a light blue background?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, questions

Why are there users whose username is shown in a light blue background?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See: [New Question Asker Features](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/new-question-asker-features/)

> Another change we made is to highlight **comment responses from the user who asked the question**.

(emphasis mine)